# New to OpenGL, working on "paint" program

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, paint

I'm taking a computer graphics course this semester at college and our first assignment is to build a program that works much like Microsoft paint. We need to set options for drawing with shapes of different colors, sizes, and transparency parameters.

I'm having trouble finding information on how to program the ability to draw with a given shape on mouse drag.  I'm not asking for the solution in code, but guidance on where to study functions that might accomplish this.

I'm completely new to OpenGL (but not C++) & I own "Computer Graphics with OpenGL" 4th ed. by Hearn & Baker. None of the topics suggest this capability.

Comment: Drawing as in "placing different shapes at a certain location using the mouse"? Or as in "using different shapes as brushes, possibly creating trails"?

Comment: Using different shapes as  brushes that leave trails.

Comment: You may use a cross-platform library (say `GLUT`) to receive mouse events on your window, and then add new shapes at fixed intervals while the mouse button is pressed at the specific location. Not the most efficient solution, but the first that came across my mind, and not so ugly unless you have a huge number of shapes on screen.

Comment: Using OpenGL to draw 2D stuff?  I know that's possible and also could be a good idea, but wouldn't there be an easier solution to this instead of learning OpenGL?  OpenGL can be very complex and most of the stuff won't help what you're doing here.

Comment: I cannot upvote @TheAmateurProgrammer 's comment enough.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably asked from you is creating a single bufferd window, or switching to draw on the front buffer, and draw some shape at the mouse pointers location, when a button is pressed (and dragged), without clearing the frontbuffer inbetween. For added robustness draw to a Frame Buffer Object attached texture, so that dragging some window will not coorupt the user's drawing.

Keywords: Set Viewport to Window size. Ortho projection to window bounds, do not use glClear (except for resetting the picture).